# Why I cannot dynamic load a Class in Servlet?

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, reflection

I recently wanted to make a Servlet demo where users can upload their class files to my server, and then I use my Servlet to read the methods in the uploaded classes. But I am stuck on the problem of not being able to read the Servlet dynamically. Here is my code：

```
package TestReflect;

@WebServlet("/showMsg")
public class showMsg extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
       
    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public showMsg() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=utf-8");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        try {
            out.println(ReadClass.getProperty());
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }       
        
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
```

```
package ReadClass;

public class ReadClass {
    public static String getProperty() throws ClassNotFoundException {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(null, "file:C:/TestClass/");
            ClassLoader classLoader = new URLClassLoader(new URL[]{url}, ReadClass.class.getClassLoader());
            Class<?> thisClass = classLoader.loadClass("add");
            return thisClass.getMethods()[0].getName();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "";
}
```

And I get the error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: add
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at ReadClass.ReadClass.getProperty(ReadClass.java:12)
    at TestReflect.showMsg.doGet(showMsg.java:48)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:624)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:110)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:494)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:104)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:1025)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:445)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1137)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:319)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

However, when I copied the same code into a normal java project, this problem did not occur and the program worked perfectly. I checked a lot of information and the solution to the most similar problem was for me to set a parent for the ClassLoader. As you can see, I have the setting in my code, but it still reports an error, do you know why?

Comment: Do you have a file called `add.class` in that folder?

Comment: Don't try to load a class that is in the default package.

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz I'm sure I have one

Comment: @MarkRotteveel This class is write by myself and put in a self-made floder.

Comment: The problem is that it is in the default package, and using things in the default package from outside the default package comes with a load of problems (i.e. usually it is not allowed). I'm not sure if that applies in this case, but it would be my first avenue of exploration if this were my own code.

Comment: A couple more things: make sure your applications server is not running under some kind of security policy (the exception doesn't indicate a security problem, but check just in case); I mean both Java security policy and OS-level restrictions. Make sure you have access to the file - i.e. try to read its contents from within the servlet. Should it be `"file:///C:/TestClass/"` (not sure)?

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos You are right, The problem is about in the server-side the path is not the things it looks like, So I think it needs an absolute path then will be done.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved. The problem is about on the server-side the path is not the thing it looks like, So I think it needs an absolute path then will be done.